# View inside View ate the same position

Tags: swift, avplayer

[Here is my simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRZkZ.png)

Here is my code:

```
player = AVPlayer(URL: url!)

        layer.player = self.player

        layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.videoView.frame.origin.x, self.videoView.frame.origin.y, self.videoView.frame.width, self.videoView.frame.height)

        print(self.videoView.frame.origin.x) //67
        print(self.videoView.frame.origin.y) //37

        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

        self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(layer)

        player.play()
```

the videoView is the greenView on my storyboard, i want to put the video on the same position of the green view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following line

```
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.videoView.frame.width, self.videoView.frame.height)
```

Making origin 0,0 will fix your issue. remember origin is based off the top left corner of SUPERview. so avPlayer.frame will have to be different from videoFrame's frame because they have different superviews.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand right, what you want, but assuming you want to put the layer at the same position of the videoView.

```
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.videoView.frame.width, self.videoView.frame.height)
```

why?

We have bounds and frames in iOS. They are pretty much the same, both are the rectangle expressed as location: (x,y) position and (width, height) size. But:

- **Bounds** are relative to its own coordinate system (0,0);
- **Frames** are relative to the superview;

You are setting a layer to your videoView, because of that the videoView is the superview of the layer, so you have to set in frame x = 0 and y = 0.